# Should I put a preposition behind an instranstive verb?

Tags: grammar, intransitive-preposition

Should I put a preposition behind an instranstive verb?

1. This music is good to listen.
2. This music is good to listen to.
3. This is the place that he took us.
4. This is the place that he took us to.
5. This is the place that I was born.
6. This is the place that I was born in.

I'm always confused with these kinds of preposition problems.
Could you please help me with it and let me know how I can decide whether to remove the preposition or not?

Comment: You should use 'to', or say "This is the place **where** he took us/I was born".

Comment: To be fair, we try not to hang prepositions on the end of sentences and actively reorganize them to remove the need as they are awkward: This is good music.  He took us to this place. etc.